# Accessing data in other Eclipse plugins

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

My problem is, that there is a plugin that generates data that I need. Is there a way to access that data?

Like getting a reference to the view or something. I have sources to the plugin, but compiling my own is not an option. I've tried getting the class (loadClass(xx)) but that just throws classnotfound.

I got the idea that extension points might be used for this? Though it doesn't help since the plugin doesn't provide one (or I have completely misunderstood Eclipse).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did kind of a hack to get info that is not exposed using reflection. the example below is for subclipse plugin (I wanted to get commited files):

```
        Field field1 = ObjectPluginAction.class.getDeclaredField("activePart");
        field1.setAccessible(true);
        SynchronizeView synchronizeView = (SynchronizeView)field1.get(pluginAction);
        Field field2 = PageBookView.class.getDeclaredField("activeRec");
        field2.setAccessible(true);
        Object pageRec = field2.get(synchronizeView);
        Field field3 = Class.forName("org.eclipse.ui.part.PageBookView$PageRec").getDeclaredField("subActionBars");
        SubActionBars bars = (SubActionBars)field3.get(pageRec);
        Field field4 = SubActionBars.class.getDeclaredField("actionHandlers");
        field4.setAccessible(true);
        Map map = (Map)field4.get(bars);
        CommitSynchronizeAction commitAction = (CommitSynchronizeAction)map.get("org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.ui.syncViewCommit");
        CommitSynchronizeActionProxy commitActionProxy = new CommitSynchronizeActionProxy(commitAction, commitComment, revisionResolver);
        commitActionProxy.run();
        m_iCommitedResources = commitActionProxy.getResources();
```

Comment: My problem was more focused on actually getting the instance of a view. But it turned out that my method did work, the views just hadn't been loaded. But still this is a good way to probe where you're not supposed to :p